# Running out of memory while installing Windows Embedded 7 Standard with updates

Tags: embedded, windows-embedded-7, answerfile

I have downloaded all current updates to my DS through WEDU, and have added these to my Answer file with "Validate > Add Applicable Updates". However, when I now try to install this image, I run out of memory.

The computer I am trying to install the image on has 2GB of memory. This is not much, but it is an *embedded* device on which I am trying to install an *embedded* OS.

The answer file I have created is very minimal, and results in a 1.3GB image before updates are added.

Is there a way to solve this issue, other than installing more memory or running Windows Update after Windows is installed?

Answer (score 0):

The cab files for the updates are listed in your answer file and will look something like this:

```
<source location="%distributionshareroot%\Packages\SecurityUpdate\x86~package_for_kb3164033~~~~6.1.1.0~1.0\Windows6.1-KB3164033-x86.cab" />
```

A standard install of WES7 SP1 will likely be in this path (and this is also the %distributionshareroot%):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1
```

Note that %distributionshareroot% is unlikely to be in your environment - it only has meaning inside ICE from what I can tell.

In your %distributionshareroot%, you will find 'install.wim'.  Make a copy of that file before doing anything else! e.g.:

```
copy /B "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\install.wim" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\install-copy.wim"
```

Then make a directory named %distributionshareroot%\mount

Next you mount install.wim, add your cab files, and dismount/commit (examples follow).  This is all done with DISM.  **Caveat: some cab files can break your installation!**  You may need to revert back to your copy of install.wim and eliminate problem updates.

To revert to your copy:

```
copy /B /Y "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\install-copy.wim" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\install.wim"
```

I am currently in the process of finding which updates are troublesome.  So far I know that kb2871997 breaks my install.  My ongoing research into this can be found at: [Updates breaking Windows Embedded Standard 7 in DISM](https://superuser.com/questions/1156494/dism-which-updates-break-wes7-windows-embedded-standard-7)

Assuming your %distributionshareroot% is where I mentioned above, the commands should look like the following.

mount:

```
DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\install.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\mount"
```

Add update KB3164033 (you can add several updates before dismounting):

```
DISM /image:"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\mount" /Add-Package /Packagepath:"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\Packages\SecurityUpdate\x86~package_for_kb3164033~~~~6.1.1.0~1.0\Windows6.1-KB3164033-x86.cab" /NoRestart
```

And finally dismount/save/commit:

```
DISM /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\mount" /Commit
```

Once you have added the updates to install.wim, you remove them from your answer file.

Comment: "Mike's answer is essentially correct (interesting it has been downvoted)." - I issue the downvote, because as you said, it's essentially correct.  It also contains commentary that indicates that, Mike, also has the same problem.  I also feel that, Mike, didn't go into enough detail.

Answer (score -2):

Did you end up figuring this out on your own?

I am having a similar issue with my Windows 7 Standard SP1.  My build system was working fine until I updated WEDU and performed 800 Security updates and fixes through WEDU.
I put this on is an Intel NUC with 4GB of memory.  This failed during the installation of the package with an out of memory exception, so to work around this I was able to increase the capacity from 4GB to 8GB of memory and the installation completed successfully.   From that point I was able to take my WIM image and apply it to my other systems with the 4GB setup.

I found an article which addresses this without increasing the memory.

[Running out of RAM and Disk Resources for Windows
Embedded Updates](http://www.annabooks.com/Articles/Articles_WES7/Disk-and-Ram-Resource-Issue-with-Windows-Embedded-Updates-Rev-1.2.pdf)

1. Create small configuration sets that are made up of the updates and hot fixes, and then
   apply them to a target image using DISM.
2. Use Windows Update to download and install the updates.
3. Use Disk Cleanup to clean out the c:\Windows\winsxs directory.

I haven't been able to come up with a solution to do this without increasing memory or performing updates after the install. But the nice part is, just perform this on a single system and then take an image of that system and apply it to your other systems after running sysprep.   That way you don't have to the updates on each individual system.