# Updates breaking Windows Embedded Standard 7 in DISM

Tags: dism, windows-embedded-7

Which updates break **Windows Embedded Standard 7** when streamed into **install.wim** using **DISM**?

I am currently researching this as I've found several updates cause the installation to fail while running inside WinPE.

Previously I added updates to the AutoUnattend.xml file and they were installed as part of the installation process, but recently I discovered this is no longer working. During the installation process I began getting this error:

```
Out of memory
```

According to Microsoft, the official solution to this is to use **DISM** to stream the updates into the **install.wim** file. This is supposed to have the additional benefits of creating a smaller image file and a faster installation.

However, I'm finding that certain updates cause this official process to fail too. One of the more common symptoms I'm finding is that after Pass1 the machine will continuously reboot.

Why is this going into a reboot cycle, and does anyone else know which specific updates cause this?

Comment: Unless you can find online where someone else has identified the problem, you'll have to go through the updates one at a time to find this answer yourself.

Comment: Agreed; thank you for confirming my suspicion.That is basically what I'm doing, although I'm saving some time by "triangulating": I add a batch of updates, if there is a problem I divide the batch in half and test to see which half of the updates is causing the problem.  I tried online sources and found it to be a waste of time.  At least when I'm done there will be an online source here!  I will continue to update at least until

Comment: That's sensible.

Comment: Once you've found the problematic one, post it here as an answer unless someone else has already correctly identified it. That way future askers will find an answer.

Comment: Absolutely.  I'm updating the question until I finish.  I'm up to two bad ones.

Comment: I have modified my question in an attempt to make it more clear what I am doing.  It has been put on hold for being too broad.  I think it is a specific question about a specific version of embedded Windows 7, and I would like to provide the answer once I complete my research.  Let me know what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: Just keep working on it. You're doing a service. Some admins tend to have itchy-triggers when it comes to closing/putting on hold. Don't let them dissuade you. So you've to this point determined that each of these updates listed above cause a problem in Windows 7 Embedded, or they cannot be streamed into the image prior to deployment?

Comment: The problem is they cannot be streamed into install.wim prior to generating an IBW image from an answer file.  The resulting DVD will reboot constantly after phase 1.  The updates seem to be OK in the answer file, but then the image fails from a lack of memory in the small OS used by install (aka Windows Preinstall).

Comment: @music2myear Using the term admins to describe the users who voted to close this question is confusing none of us are admins not moderators

Comment: "repeatedly the install.wim file is now about 20% larger than it would be if I'd streamed all 200 of the patches I've tested so far in one mount-stream-unmount process." I believe there is a dism command that solves this problem here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj963514(v=winembedded.81).aspx

Comment: Good point about the DISM switch.  I have not experimented with using the version 8 DISM against a version 7 image.  The version 7 DISM does not have that switch.  I believe that switch also makes it impossible to later remove updates.  I'll give it a try when I'm done finding the bad ones.

Comment: @trindflo, nice job on this.  I tried to do a little cleanup to conform to site guidelines, moving the "answer"-related portion to the answer, which also eliminated the confusing double list.  You might want to verify what I did and fine-tune it if needed.

Comment: Looks great fixer1234.  I have learned from the experience.  This site has the best dependable answers, and I think that is because it is community governed.  It is something I would like to participate in.

Comment: I tried using the version 8 DISM to reduce the size of the resulting image and received `Error                 DISM   DISM MSI Manager: PID=5080 Failed to find Offline Aware MSI.dll from image(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded Standard 7\DSSP1\mount\Windows), hr = -2147024894 - CMsiManager::Initialize(hr:0x80070002)` that I interpret to mean a DLL from within the image must process the **/StartComponentCleanup** switch.  In any case I ended up with a `startcomponentcleanup option is not recognized in this context` error when I tried it.  Solution seems to be to start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of someone else who already knows, I'm researching this myself, testing one update at a time. See the list of problem updates I've found below.

I am using **Windows Embedded Developer Update** (WEDU) to collect updates, adding batches of updates with **DISM**, and making a copy of **install.wim**.  When a batch of updates result in failure, I restore the previous copy of install.wim, divide the batch in half, and repeat the process.

*Worth noting: The DISM/Streaming method is supposed to decrease the total size of the install media. However, by mounting - streaming - unmounting - testing - remounting - streaming again - unmounting - testing - etc., repeatedly the install.wim file is now about 20% larger than it would be if I'd streamed all 200 of the patches I've tested so far in one mount-stream-unmount process.*

I intend to continue adding problem updates to this answer as I gather further data.

In the range of kb2425227 through kb3059317 (inclusive), I have found the following updates to cause the installation media to be unusable when these updates are added to the install.wim file using DISM:

- kb2871997
- kb2973351
- kb2982378
- kb2984972
- kb2992611
- kb3003743
- kb3004375
- kb3011780
- kb3023562
- kb3033929
- kb3035131
- kb3046049
- kb3057154

And I am going to stop now because I just found a pattern.  Each of the failing updates in the list above has filenames that contain the string: **"x86_microsoft-windows-lsa"** in the manifest.  Based on this, I excluded all other updates containing the string and found my installation ran to completion.  I have included Security Updates up to kb3170455 and Updates up to kb3153731 in this final test.

I have not proven the updates in the following list cause the reboot problem I was seeing, and I don't intend to test each one to prove it.  The following list are updates I believe would cause the problem, and excluding them was sufficient to solve the issue I was seeing.

Security Updates:

- kb3060716
- kb3061518
- kb3067505
- kb3071756
- kb3083992
- kb3088195
- kb3097966
- kb3126587
- kb3146706
- kb3149090
- kb3153171
- kb3161561

Updates:

- kb2973337
- kb3023607
- kb3080079